Spatie\Image\Exceptions\CouldNotLoadImage: Could not load image at path
We are running are PHPUnit test in our Gitlab-CI. Every now and then some test are failing because of an exception:
Spatie\Image\Exceptions\CouldNotLoadImage: Could not load image at path `/builds/api/storage/media-library/temp/u9hn06FL7CIz4gDf3PClKfiCsP6CCNEn/eKb9zA0BzpXjZg1CDSityXjDUcewN0yfthumb-xs.jpeg`
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/image/src/Exceptions/CouldNotLoadImage.php:11
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/image/src/Drivers/Gd/GdDriver.php:92
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/image/src/Image.php:49
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/Conversions/Actions/PerformManipulationsAction.php:34
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/Conversions/Actions/PerformConversionAction.php:30
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/Conversions/FileManipulator.php:71
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php:240
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/Conversions/FileManipulator.php:70
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/Conversions/Jobs/PerformConversionsJob.php:30
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:36
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php:41
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:93
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:35
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:662
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php:128
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:144
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:119
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php:132
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php:123
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:144
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:119
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php:122
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php:70
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php:102
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SyncQueue.php:43
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php:59
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php:247
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php:230
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php:77
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bus/PendingDispatch.php:193
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:388
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/Conversions/FileManipulator.php:98
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/Conversions/FileManipulator.php:40
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/MediaCollections/Filesystem.php:37
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/MediaCollections/FileAdder.php:438
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/MediaCollections/FileAdder.php:420
/builds/api/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/MediaCollections/FileAdder.php:339
/builds/api/database/factories/ProjectPool/ProjectFactory.php:88
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:713
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php:240
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:712
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php:240
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:711
/builds/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:289
/builds/api/tests/Feature/API/Mutations/ProjectPool/UpdateProjectTest.php:107

It is always a different test-case which is failing and sometimes no test-case fails and our Pipeline succeeds. So it is not a reproducable error. Also when running the tests locally no error occurs.
We are using Minio both locally and in CI as our Laravel disk.
Media-Library-Version: v11.4.7
My guess is that when copying the file from S3/Minio to the local temp folder fails. But I cannot verify this, because the package does not check the success of copying these files...

can't you do this if (!Storage::exists($path)) { then do the again the copy, this will prevent your guess

I'm getting the same issue when trying to create images. When I actually ssh into the container the image is actually there that it claims does not exist. Only started to happen when I upgraded Spatie laravel media libarary.

I would suggest trying imagick as the image driver to see if that changes anything.
You would have to enable imagick PHP extension.
In .env you can specify the IMAGE_DRIVER, also take a look at media-library.image_driver.
I managed to get my media-library working with this change.
Edit:
I got my Gd driver working by following this accepted answer.
Call to undefined function Intervention\Image\Gd\imagecreatefromjpeg() Laravel 8 + Docker desktop 4.4.4
I was missing some of the Gd lib dependencies.

I had the same issue and it appeared that my php didn't support webp format. After enabling webp in php gd this problem disappeared.
Try to debug your path like this:
$path = 'your_path';
$handle = fopen($path, 'r');
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($path));
fclose($handle);

// in most cases exception will be trown here 
// but in original code this line is suppressed with @ 
$image = imagecreatefromstring($contents);


This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
